Optimizing rear derailleur cage length
So I'm doing the last bits of research which parts I'm getting for my next build (for bikepacking).
With a 30/46t or 30/44t crankset and 9sp 11-42 cassette in theory I'd need a rear derailleur with a 47t capacity. However, I'm not planning to ever run Large-Large or Small-Small. This would get me to effectively being able to use 30t upfront with 18-42t of my cassette and 46t with 11-34t (tooth difference <=41). With 30/44t I would even be able to use 30t upfront with 15-42t of my cassette, i.e I would only missing out on the two-three smallest and the largest sprocket respectively.
As a shorter cage rear derailleur offers better shifting (precision, responsiveness, tension) I'm thinking of getting a rear derailleur with 41t capacity instead of 47. Lower profile probably doesn't matter too much as it's gonna be a 29" bike (at least 50-622).
Does it make sense to do this kind of calculation and go for a smaller cage or is it nice theory but in practice not worth the risk and I might regret this when I'm somewhere in the outback of Bosnia or Albania this autumn?

However, I'm not planning to ever run Large-Large...  It's best to "plan" on using that, because if you build a bike where that's not supported and you somehow wind up there, things start snapping and breaking.

“Everyone has a plan until they get punched in the mouth.”.
What you need is a bike than does not break when things don't go according to plan.  Bikepacking is probably not the place to be trading robustness for performance.

Following on from @AndrewHenle, this is a failure that's likely to occur at a particularly bad moment, like dropping the last sprocket while trying to power up a hill - lots of torque and a likelihood of a very sudden stop if you lock the back wheel or even if you snap the chain. Can you unclip that fast? I have been known to but wouldn't want to rely on it. Derailleur damage is another likely failure mode.

With certain touring triple builds where the granny is an extreme bailout gear (for example I have a bike with 50/38/24 this applies to), doing what you're talking about can make sense there because you're not losing much by relegating the small ring and half or more of its cassette combinations to being slack; you only care about the biggest 1 or 2 cogs.
For 46/30 bikes in general, most of which are built with some kind of nod to being ridden offroad or on bad/primitive roads, I mostly wouldn't do this unless perhaps only allowing the small/small crossgear to be slack. The reason is that even though you'll want to spend as much time as you can in the 46, when you do rougher stuff you'll often tend to want to be in the 30 and all over the cassette, and you don't want to worry about any restrictions then. You don't want to be thinking about whether you're dropping below 17t in back, and in fact you probably will want to do just that (2:1 is often regarded as an important offroad gear; see the popularity of 32:16 on SS MTBs).
There's the semi-jokingly-named gearing concept of "1x plus granny" (a callback to "half-step plus granny" triples of the past). In these drivetrains, a 46/30, 44/28, etc is set up with the big ring in the nominal chainline position, as though it were a 1x, and the little ring goes inboard around where the small ring on a triple would usually live. The little ring is then relegated to being a bailout gear. In the right application this can make sense, but yours doesn't sound like it.
Never set up any bike without the chain length needed to safely be accidentally shifted into large-large. All the total capacity cheating must be in the small/small combinations.

Triples make it much more feasible to assume you won't be in big-big or small-small, because the chance of shifting through all your sprockets without shifting even one chainring is reduced.  I still wouldn't rely on it to avoid big-big, because gradually-changing gradients when you're tired lead to mistakes like that, and we should design out bad consequences, but a too-long chain in small-small (or small-smallish; the difference between 11T and 13T doesn't make much difference here) might slap or slip, but shouldn't break stuff

The second paragraph is a pretty good description of how I use my 30/46 gravel/endurance road bike with an RD-R7000-GS rear mech.  I haven't tested it in anger yet, only on an easy road, but exceeding both the max rear sprocket and total capacity by 2 teeth seems initially fine (11-36 on my gravel wheelset)  If that goes well, I may look at whether I can set up the front mech to handle 30/46 and 30/48 without adjustment, and have 30/48 × 11-34 road, 30/46 × 11-36 gravel)

The assumption that a short cage derailleur is more reactive is not always true. To my experience, reactivity is mostly influenced by how close the upper jockey wheel is to the cassette, that's influenced not by the capacity, but the parallelogram and the offset between the upper jockey wheel and the axis between the cage pivot and the lower jockey wheel.
I can see the case of shorter cages being less reactive for road derailleurs, that have very little offset, and that have a parallelogram that may be optimised for the small cassettes rather than the larger ones. As personal example, I have a gravel bike with the 2x GRX (small offset then). I tried the Sunrace cassette 11-36, that has a better sequence in theory (11-12-13-15-17...) that the Shimano one (11-13-15-19...), but I reverted to the Shimano one because of reactivity (I needed to adjust the b-screw to clear the larger cassette, but because the offset is limited, the upper jockey wheel was to far from the small cogs to have a good shifting).
On chain retention, I would not again assume that short cage derailleurs are better: it is true if there's only a spring, but offroad derailleurs have now clutches, that are meant to improve chain retention with high capacities.
So in short, as I understand it, the best reactivity is achieved by having the derailleur that operates within its design limits. If you want to run 46/30 and 11/42, in 9 speeds, there's the Microshift Advent (that also has a clutch). In 11-speed, there's also the CUES 6000/8000 (it's 46/31 - 11/45 though). The proposition of using a shorter cage also introduces another risk in the context of remote bikepacking: breaking the derailleur in a moment of inattention. Given that products exist that meet these specifications exist, I don't see the benefit of going "off-spec" for a marginal improvement.
